# ViewPager working with fragments updating offscreen view instead of main view

Tags: android, android-viewpager, adapter, fragment

**EDIT 2**
this is my adapter in case it helps anyone

```
 public static class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return sDrawables.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ImageViewFragment.POSITION_KEY, position);
            return ImageViewFragment.newInstance(args);
        }


        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            String name = "";
            try{
            name = sNames[position];
            }catch(IllegalArgumentException e){
                name = "error";
            }
            return name;
        }

        public int getItemPosition(){
            return POSITION_NONE;
        }
    }
```

**EDIT**
Based on the response of Sino Raj just changing:

```
MainFragmentName fragment= (MainFragmentName )mViewPager.getChildAt(mPosition);
```

for:

```
ImageViewFragment fragment = (ImageViewFragment)mViewPager.getAdapter().instantiateItem(mViewPager, mViewPager.getCurrentItem());
```

I am getting now always the next item on the pager to change, the one on the right if im going on that direction or the one in the left other wise. any ideas on that?

I'm getting the following error:

```
04-16 16:01:16.952: W/System.err(29027): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-16 16:01:16.952: W/System.err(29027):    at catalog.ImageViewFragment.onChangePicture(ImageViewFragment.java:165)
04-16 16:01:16.952: W/System.err(29027):    at catalog.MenuFragment.changeMainPic(MenuFragment.java:231)  
04-16 16:01:16.952: W/System.err(29027):    at catalog.MenuFragment.access$6(MenuFragment.java:224)
04-16 16:01:16.952: W/System.err(29027):    at catalog.MenuFragment$1.onClick(MenuFragment.java:106)
04-16 16:01:16.952: W/System.err(29027):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4202)
04-16 16:01:16.952: W/System.err(29027):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17340)
04-16 16:01:16.952: W/System.err(29027):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
04-16 16:01:16.952: W/System.err(29027):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-16 16:01:16.952: W/System.err(29027):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-16 16:01:16.952: W/System.err(29027):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
04-16 16:01:16.952: W/System.err(29027):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-16 16:01:16.952: W/System.err(29027):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-16 16:01:16.952: W/System.err(29027):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
04-16 16:01:16.952: W/System.err(29027):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
04-16 16:01:16.952: W/System.err(29027):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**END EDIT**

I have been working on a catalog like app for android, is relatively simple and relay on fragment support v4.

The idea is to have an array of images showing on a view pager, the view pager's child is a fragment with an ImageView.

The View pager is contained on another fragment that overlay a vertical scroll to display different pictures of the main picture and when clicked the main picture will change to the chosen one.

Everything is working as expected but the main picture update function. When the thumbnails from the vertical scroll view are clicked the main picture will change but the problem is some times instead of the main picture of the current page changing it will change the one from the offscreen view.

The part of the code where I am changing the picture is this:

```
private void changeMainPic(String sName){

    try{
        if(mViewPager != null){
            String tName = sName.replace("_s.jpg", ".jpg");


            mainIv = (ImageView)mViewPager.getChildAt(mPosition).findViewById(R.id.mainImageView);

            InputStream is2 = getActivity().getAssets().open(tName);
            Bitmap bm2 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is2);
            mainIv.setImageBitmap(bm2);
            is2.close();
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("Pictures","error on main iv "+e);
    }
}
```

Any idea of what is wrong? if you need any other part of the code please tell me.

Thank you very much in advance to everyone

David

Comment: did you try overriding `getItemPosition(Object object)` in your adapter and returning `POSITION_NONE`?

Comment: Im sorry Lalit Poptani, but I dont really understand where do I need to do that exactly?

Comment: in your ViewPager's Adapter class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change `changeMainPic(String sName)` in to this,

Inside of Activity,

```
private void changeMainPic(String sName){
    try{
        if(mViewPager != null){
            String tName = sName.replace("_s.jpg", ".jpg");
            MainFragmentName fragment= (MainFragmentName )mPagerAdapter.getChildAt(mPosition);
            fragment.onChangePicture(tName);//Call a public function inside of fragment

        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("Pictures","error on main iv "+e);
    }
}
```

Inside of Fragment,

```
ImageView mainIv=null;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{   
      View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout, container, false);
      mainIv=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.mainImageView);
      return view;
}
public void onChangePicture(tName)
   {
            InputStream is2 = getActivity().getAssets().open(tName);
            Bitmap bm2 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is2);
            mainIv.setImageBitmap(bm2);
            is2.close();
   }
```

**Edit--2**
implement OnPageChangeListener in your activity(i.e,`Activity implements OnPageChangeListener`) then you get then override functions,

```
public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0)
    {}
    public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2)
    {}
    public void onPageSelected(int position) 
    {
        mPosition=position;
    }
```

**Edit--3**
edited adapter...

```
public static class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private FragmentManager fragmentManager=null;
        public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
            fragmentManager=fm;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return sDrawables.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ImageViewFragment.POSITION_KEY, position);
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().commitAllowingStateLoss();
            return ImageViewFragment.newInstance(args);
        }
        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            String name = "";
            try{
            name = sNames[position];
            }catch(IllegalArgumentException e){
                name = "error";
            }
            return name;
        }

        public int getItemPosition(){
            return POSITION_NONE;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your replay, it does make a lot of sense, however as mViewPager. getChildAt() return a view it cannot be casted as fragment, unless I am missing something.

Comment: sorry, i have updated. I just edited your code without looking that is a view pager. Just change view pager into mPagerAdapter, then that works fine..

Comment: Thanks again, please take a look at my update, your method works with that little change I done, however it does not work with mPager Adapter either, now, the main picture is changing but always on the next view that is off screen.

Comment: Hey i really appreciate your help, now I am getting this error, if you could please refer to my question update

Comment: Check now, I have updated. Replay must. If problem has not solved, please check whether the image is null or not?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28290/discussion-between-david-and-sino-raj)

Comment: Image is not null, in fact image is changing, only on the next neighboring fragment.

Comment: Check the 'mPosition' on before changing. When that position is greater or less than one, then position is the problem.Because the View pager is always initiate the next fragment. So please check that..